# How to solve: java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java

This is a program to parse a JSON structure in a streaming manner.
It is 10 PM here, my brain is tired,  and that is why I seem to be not able to figure out why I am getting the exception:
   java.io.Exception: Stream closed.

If the experts out here can help me get rid of this exception, I will be thankful for helping me solve this problem at this time of the night.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

import java.util.Properties;

public class JacksonStreaming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Entered Main");
        try {
            new JacksonStreaming().getNames();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

Properties prop = new Properties();
String filePath = "";
final String[] path = new String[] {"myReport", "docReports", "part1/.", "myAnalysis", "matches", "name"};

void getNames()  {
    System.out.println("Entered getNames"); 
    //final String resourceName = "C:/Users/Ilango/ellyworkspace/JacksonStreamingFindData/src/jsonFormattedModified.json";
    JsonNode rootNode;


            try {
                //InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
                BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Ilango/ellyworkspace/JacksonStreamingFindData/src/jsonFormattedModified.json"));
                System.out.println("fileReader is: " + fileReader); 
                rootNode = jsonMapper.readTree(fileReader);
                System.out.println("Return value of jsonMapper.readTree is: " +rootNode);
                findByPath(rootNode);
                JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(fileReader);
                System.out.println("JsonParser is: " + jsonParser);

                int pathIndex = 0;
                List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
                boolean breakOnClose = false;


                //try {
                    //try {
                        while (jsonParser.nextToken() != null) {
                            final String fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
                            if (fieldName == null) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (breakOnClose && fieldName.equals(path[path.length - 2])) {
                                System.out.println("Stopping search at end of node " + fieldName);
                                break;
                            }
                            if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            // System.out.println("Field " + fieldName);
                            if (pathIndex >= path.length - 1) {
                                if (fieldName.equals(path[path.length - 1])) {
                                    // move from field name to field value.
                                    try {
                                        jsonParser.nextToken();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 
                                    String name;
                                    //try {
                                        name = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
                                    //} catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        //e.printStackTrace();
                                    //}
                                    if (name == null) {
                                        throw new RuntimeException("No value exists for field " + fieldName);
                                    }
                                    names.add(name);
                                    System.out.println("Found " + fieldName + " value: " + name);
                                }
                            } else if (fieldName.equals(path[pathIndex])) {
                                System.out.println("Found node " + path[pathIndex]);
                                pathIndex++;
                                if (pathIndex >= path.length - 1) {
                                    System.out.println("Looking for names ...");
                                    breakOnClose = true;
                                    // prevent breaking on "matches" value json-token.
                                    try {
                                        jsonParser.nextFieldName();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

            } 






            void findByPath(JsonNode jn) {
                System.out.println("Entered findByPath");   
                JsonNode matchesNamesNode = jn;
                for (int i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
                    matchesNamesNode = matchesNamesNode.path(path[i]);
                }
                if (matchesNamesNode.isMissingNode()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("No node with names found.");
                }
                System.out.println("Tree names: " + matchesNamesNode.findValuesAsText("name"));
            }


     }// end of class JacksonStreaming
      def setCount(count: Int) {
        this.count = count
      }
    }
```

**Stack trace:**

```
Entered Main
Entered getNames
fileReader is: java.io.BufferedReader@33e5ccce
Return value of jsonMapper.readTree is: {"type":"ImportantIncidentInfo","incidentTimestamp":"2014-05-15T10:09:27.989-05:00","numOfMatches":4,"myReport":{"docReports":{"part1/.":{"path":["unknown"],"myAnalysis":{"matches":[{"id":{"major":1,"minor":0},"name":"US SSN","position":13,"string":" 636-12-4567 "},{"id":{"major":3,"minor":0},"name":"MasterCard Credit Card Number","position":35,"string":" 5424-1813-6924-3685 "}]},"cleanedUpData":[{"startPosition":0,"endPosition":65,"frameContent":""}],"minedMetadata":{"Content-Encoding":"ISO-8859-1","Content-Type":"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"},"deducedMetadata":{"Content-Type":"text/html; iso-8859-1"}},"part2/.":{"path":["unknown"],"myAnalysis":{"matches":[{"id":{"major":1,"minor":0},"name":"SSN","position":3,"string":" 636-12-4567\r"},{"id":{"major":3,"minor":0},"name":"MasterCard Credit Card Number","position":18,"string":"\n5424-1813-6924-3685\r"}]},"cleanedUpData":[{"startPosition":0,"endPosition":44,"frameContent":""}],"minedMetadata":{"Content-Encoding":"windows-1252","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=windows-1252"},"deducedMetadata":{"Content-Type":"text/plain; iso-8859-1"}}}},"whatSetItOffEntry":{"action":"Log","component":{"type":"aComponent","components":[{"type":"PatternComponent","patterns":[1],"not":false}],"not":false},"ticketInfo":{"createIncident":true,"tags":[],"seeRestrictedIds":[{"type":"userGroup","name":"SiteMasters","description":"Group for SiteMasters","masters":["04fb02a2bc0fba"],"members":[],"id":"04fade"}]},"letmeknowInfo":{"createNotification":true,"contactNames":["someguy@gmail.com"]}},"seeRestrictedIds":["04fade66c0"],"status":"New","timeStamps":["2015-05-15T10:09:27.989-05:00"],"count":1}
Entered findByPath
Tree names: [US SSN, MasterCard Credit Card Number]
JsonParser is: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser@23223dd8
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:278)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.loadMore(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:153)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1855)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:571)
    at com.myorg.myapi.JacksonStreaming.getNames(JacksonStreaming.java:55)
    at com.myorg.myapi.JacksonStreaming.main(JacksonStreaming.java:19)
```

Comment: Please post the complete Stack Trace of your exception

Comment: Maybe look at the problem tomorrow morning at 8 am after a good coffee.

Comment: @Quality Analyst: You are right. A cup of coffee would have helped a lot.

Comment: The way to solve this exception is not to close the stream. But editing your question so that it no longer exhibits the problem is contrary to the purpose of this site.

Comment: You are right. That was an innocent mistake. I was going to delete the solution part fron the question myself. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is what is wrong with your code (see comments):

```
// you create a BufferedReader (no problems per se)
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Ilango/ellyworkspace/JacksonStreamingFindData/src/jsonFormattedModified.json"));

 // this consumes the fileReader stream
rootNode = jsonMapper.readTree(fileReader);

findByPath(rootNode);

// the next line is where the problem is happening
// fileReader has already been consumed, so the call to createParser() must fail
JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(fileReader); // java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

The solution to your problem is either make a copy of the stream, or don't consume it a second time after it has already been read.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I changed the offending to make a new stream. I have also updated the code with the solution.